# Calculate date-difference, compering rows and creating new once

Tags: sql-server

I have a application that creates a new row (in the first table above) every 30 second if the application is "online". If, the gap between each row is bigger than 30 second then the application is "offline".

This is the table:

```
----Date---- 
2018-07-05 15:02:41.903
2018-07-05 15:04:05.907
2018-07-05 15:06:10.433
2018-07-05 15:06:40.433
2018-07-05 15:07:40.430
2018-07-05 15:07:10.430
```

I want create a table that shows UpTime (status = 1) and DownTime (status = 0) with start and end dates for each period.

I have manage to get to this point:

```
----Date---------------------Difference-------------Status- 
2018-07-05 15:02:41.903           30                  1
2018-07-05 15:04:05.907           84                  0
2018-07-05 15:06:10.433          125                  0
2018-07-05 15:06:40.433           30                  1
2018-07-05 15:07:10.430           30                  1
2018-07-05 15:07:40.430           30                  1
```

with this code:

```
  WITH    rows AS
    (
    SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [LAST_UPDATE]) AS rn
    FROM    [dbo].[X] 
    )


SELECT  [LAST_UPDATE],
    DATEDIFF(second, pDataDate, [LAST_UPDATE]) as Differance,
    case when (DATEDIFF(second, pDataDate, [LAST_UPDATE])-30) > 1 then 0 else 
1 end as DownOrUp 
FROM    (
    SELECT  *,
            LAG([LAST_UPDATE]) OVER (ORDER BY [LAST_UPDATE]) pDataDate
    FROM    rows
    ) q
WHERE   pDataDate IS NOT NULL
```

The table below is what I want (duration calculated approximately). Downtime period counts for: Last timestamp where status was 1 to last timestamp while status = 0.

```
------Status-----------StartDate-------------------EndDate---------Duration--
       Down    2018-07-05 15:02:41.903  2018-07-05 15:06:10.433      270
         UP    2018-07-05 15:06:40.433  2018-07-05 15:07:40.430       60
```

Any suggestions ??

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do? It's difficult to infer your intentions from code that isn't working as you want it to.

Comment: I have a application that creates a new row (in the first table above) every 30 second if the application is "online". If, the gap between each row is bigger than 30 second then the application is "offline".

Comment: and why isn't the up time 90?

Comment: If the application only inserts a row when it's online, then isn't every insertion the status is 1 and you just need to figure out how long it was down? And how do you know it was down for the entire time? i.e there's a 30 second fuzzy here.

Comment: I have trouble seeing out the solution is possible given all numbers end in 0 except  5 and 4... so 9 or 1 must be the ending number?

Comment: If the gap between each inserted row is bigger than 30 seconds then it is a indication of it has been down...

Comment: but the actual timestamp means the application is up, as of that time, correct? This would mean your numbers are off in the expected results and you should have 3 rows for the time down.

Comment: Yes, that is correct - the actual timestamp means the application is up, as of that time, but the compering it with previous row decides if it has been down (gap > 30 sec). Possibly my expected results in last table (handmade), can't really see it though....

Comment: Downtime period counts for: Last timestamp where status was 1 to last timestamp while status = 0. (will correct my example)

Comment: I do something similar, but instead of inserting a new row I have (Started, WatchDog and Ended) columns. I update Watchdog column with current time every N seconds and when it completes successfully both watchdog and ended columns have the same value. (Also there is an ID column which is unique to a process so different processes can update their own rows)

Comment: You're likely going to run into timestamp drift with your approach. Don't assume there is a perfect interval between inserts.
P.S. Sounds like you are trying to write a keep alive/watchdog mechanism.

Comment: Any one willing to try to get from my first table to the last one (forget my middle table and code)  ?  Would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have something that will work for you. I'm not certain how efficient it's going to be over a large data set, and I'm sure it's possible to collapse it into fewer steps, but hopefully it will at least suffice to explain the idea. First, let's set up our sample data, group each timestamp with the one that precedes it, and figure out which intervals represent uptime vs. downtime.

```
declare @x table (last_update datetime);
insert @x values
    ('2018-07-05 15:02:41.903'),
    ('2018-07-05 15:04:05.907'),
    ('2018-07-05 15:06:10.433'),
    ('2018-07-05 15:06:40.433'),
    ('2018-07-05 15:07:40.430'),
    ('2018-07-05 15:07:10.430');

select
    start_time = lag(X.last_update) over (order by X.last_update),
    end_time = X.last_update,
    up = case when coalesce(datediff(second, lag(X.last_update) over (order by X.last_update), X.last_update), 0) <= 30 then 1 else 0 end,
    number = row_number() over (order by X.last_update)
from
    @x X;
```

[image]

I probably don't need to explain much here as it's very close to the result you've already achieved. All I did was to add a `number` column whose values increase as the timestamps increase; my reason for doing so will become clear in a bit. The next question we need to answer is: which of these intervals represent a continuation of the preceding interval, and which represent the beginnings of new intervals? I gather from your question that you consider consecutive periods of greater than 30 seconds to represent a continual period of downtime, while consecutive periods of 30 seconds or less represent a continual period of uptime. So what I'll do is to put the query we already have into a CTE, then use the `lag` function again to determine whether each interval has the same status as its predecessor. This yields a column called `continues`, which is 1 for intervals that represent a continuation of the preceding interval and 0 for those that represent the start of a new period.

```
with Intervals as
(
    select
        start_time = lag(X.last_update) over (order by X.last_update),
        end_time = X.last_update,
        up = case when coalesce(datediff(second, lag(X.last_update) over (order by X.last_update), X.last_update), 0) <= 30 then 1 else 0 end,
        number = row_number() over (order by X.last_update)
    from
        @x X
)
select
    I.*,
    continues = case when lag(I.up) over (order by I.start_time) = I.up then 1 else 0 end
from
    Intervals I;
```

[image]

What I want next is a value that I can put into a `group by` clause that will aggregate successive intervals correctly. Each record in the preceding result set where `continues = 0` represents the beginning of a new interval, which should be grouped with all immediately subsequent records for which `continues = 1`. In other words, I want each record to have an identifier that increases for each record where `continues = 0` and remains unchanged if `continues = 1`. I can do this by taking the `number` column that I added to your initial query and subtracting the number of continuations encountered thus far in the result set:

```
with Intervals as
(
    select
        start_time = lag(X.last_update) over (order by X.last_update),
        end_time = X.last_update,
        up = case when coalesce(datediff(second, lag(X.last_update) over (order by X.last_update), X.last_update), 0) <= 30 then 1 else 0 end,
        number = row_number() over (order by X.last_update)
    from
        @x X
),
IntervalExtents as
(
    select
        I.*,
        continues = case when lag(I.up) over (order by I.start_time) = I.up then 1 else 0 end
    from
        Intervals I
)
select
    X.*,
    group_number = number - sum(continues) over (order by number)
from
    IntervalExtents X;
```

[image]

Now all that remains is to decide exactly how to aggregate the groups identified in this query. This is where your expected results seem a little strange to me. Your sample data set has timestamps at 15:06:10, 15:06:40, 15:07:10, and 15:07:40. Surely this means that the system was online from 15:06:10 to 15:07:40, an interval of 90 seconds, since we have entries every 30 seconds over that period. But your sample results show uptime from 15:06:40 to 15:07:40, an interval of 60 seconds. I'm guessing that was a mistake; if it wasn't, you can still get your expected results by tinkering with the query I'm about to show, determining the interval extents differently for uptime periods vs. downtime. Here's the way I think the final query should look:

```
with Intervals as
(
    select
        start_time = lag(X.last_update) over (order by X.last_update),
        end_time = X.last_update,
        up = case when coalesce(datediff(second, lag(X.last_update) over (order by X.last_update), X.last_update), 0) <= 30 then 1 else 0 end,
        number = row_number() over (order by X.last_update)
    from
        @x X
),
IntervalExtents as
(
    select
        I.*,
        continues = case when lag(I.up) over (order by I.start_time) = I.up then 1 else 0 end
    from
        Intervals I
),
IntervalGroups as
(
    select
        X.*,
        group_number = number - sum(continues) over (order by number)
    from
        IntervalExtents X
)
select
    [status] = case when min(G.up) = 1 then 'Up' else 'Down' end,
    start_time = min(G.start_time),
    end_time = max(G.end_time),
    duration = datediff(second, min(G.start_time), max(G.end_time))
from
    IntervalGroups G
group by
    G.group_number
having
    min(G.start_time) is not null
order by
    G.group_number;
```

[image]

Note the `HAVING` clause that I've used here. It requires that each group of intervals being aggregated contain at least record with a non-null `start_time`. This prevents the initial 15:02:41 timestamp from showing up as a null-second interval of uptime. The reason I've waited until this step to perform this check is so that you'll still have that raw data available if I've misinterpreted any of your requirements and you need to adjust the query. If it's working as desired, then you could simply change the `IntervalExtents` CTE to only include records where `I.start_time is not null`, which would obviate the `HAVING` clause on the final `SELECT`.

That should be it. Hopefully if this doesn't answer your question, it will at least get you started.